# Ambiguity in a distance between a point on a line and a plane

Tags: vectors

I recently had this question on one of my math tests involving vectors:

Find the exact distance between a point on the line *l* : $\frac{x+2}{2} = \frac{4-z}{6}, y=5$ and the plane containing the line $(x-5, y+3, z+2) = \mu(1,0,3)$.

I found the question to be very ambiguous since there are an infinite amount of planes containing the line $(x-5, y+3, z+2) = \mu(1,0,3)$. (therefore the must be an infinite amount of planes containing a single line that will intersect the line *l* and in only one case will they not intersect)  This means there is no exact distance between a point on the line *l* and the plane containing the line $(x-5, y+3, z+2) = \mu(1,0,3)$.

Does anyone have a valid solution for this problem, have I overlooked something?

Comment: For your information, I got this question wrong by writing (No Distance) and was awarded 1/3 marks for method.

Comment: Perhaps “the plane” was meant to be “the parallel plane.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line lies in the $y = 5$ plane; the second lies in the $y = -3$ plane. But I don't think that makes any difference.

Your argument is pretty solid. For any point $Q$ on the first line, there is SOME plane $P$ containing both the second line and $Q$, and for $P$, the distance is zero. But for any point $Q$ on the line, there's also some plane $P'$ containing the second line and \emph{not} containing $Q$ (this actually requires a little proof, and the y-values argument helps), and in this case, the distance is positive.

It's a horribly worded question. I cannot imagine what the questioner was hoping to get as an answer.

Comment: Now let's suppose the teacher in fact misprinted the test and instead there was typo on the direction vector of the line contained on the plane. \mu(1, 0, 3) was instead \mu(1, 0, **-3**). The direction vectors are then effectively the same.  There must exist a plane that contains both lines.  My argument still holds true?

Comment: In that case, there is indeed a plane that contains both lines, so the smallest possible distance (over all planes) is 0, and one can even easily compute the largest possible distance (which is the perpendicular distance between the two lines). Even so it'd be a horrible question, because there's still no way to find "the exact distance" without knowing more about which plane is being discussed.

Comment: Thank you for you input on this matter, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: $2+3=5\ne0$. Doesn’t the second line lie in the $y=-3$ plane instead?

Comment: Yep...I'll edit. Thanks!